# Phone doesn't install app from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an ace advance phone, in the past i was able to debug my app in the phone from eclipse but now i can't, even whit a simple hello world program..what happen is that sometimes i click run on eclipse and my phone vibrates twice and the installation is finished, and sometimes the installation take a wile and then says installation fail..i tried another phone that i have and works fine, i believe is a problem from my ace advance i restart it from fabric and everything but still the same result..what could be the problem? please help me i tried everything already..the phone is debugging mode

Comment: Does everything include a hard dump / resetting to factory state?

Comment: yes it does..sorry for the vague question..what information do you think you need? i am very new to android development..thank you very much for the help